# Google Sheet Script: Copy 1 row to multiple sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a google script that will allow me to move 1 row of data to 2 different google sheet pages on the same spreadsheet. The purpose of this is to track when inventory is has been received by a company, but when the product is being ordered for both offices.

The spreadsheet has 12 columns with a dropdown bar selector in Column A for location (values to watch), and a checkbox in column K to indicate the product was received by the location.

It currently works like this:

1. If the value in Column A = "Location 1" and received is checked in page "Order Sheet", move data row to sheet "Location 1 received" and delete original row
2. If the value in Column A = "Location 2" and received is checked in page "Order Sheet", move data row to sheet "Location 2 received"

I want to implement a way to copy this data row to both received sheets if the value in Column A = "Both".

- If the value in Column A = "Both" and received is checked in page "Order Sheet", move data row to sheet "Location 1 received" and "Location 2 received"

Right now sending the data row to Location 1 and Location 2 works perfectly however I get an error for trying to copy the data twice to 2 different sheet pages. The error I am receiving is:

> Exception: The coordinates of the target range are outside the dimensions of the sheet.
> at moveToReceived(moveToReceived:26:65)

Is there a way for me to copy the selected range of data to both sheet pages when the value is "Both"?

My code:

```
function moveToReceived(e) {
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;

  const valueToWatch1 = "Location 1";
  const valueToWatch2 = "Location 2";
  const valueToWatch3 = "Both";

  const dest1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Location 1 Received");
  const dest2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Location 2 Received");

  if (src.getName() != "Order Sheet" || r.columnStart != 11 || r.rowStart == 1) return;

  if (r.offset(0, -10).getValue() == valueToWatch1) {
    src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12));
    src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);

  } else if (r.offset(0, -10).getValue() == valueToWatch2) {
    src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).moveTo(dest2.getRange(dest2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12));
    src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);

  } else if (r.offset(0, -10).getValue() == valueToWatch3) {

    src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).copyTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12))
    src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).copyTo(dest2.getRange(dest2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12))
    src.deleteRow(r.rowStart);
  }
};
```

Comment: In order to correctly unedrstand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect?

Comment: Would you be able to share an example sheet so that it is easier to take a look and understand where the script it going wrong?

Comment: I have recreated a similar version of this script myself and was not able to reproduce this error.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a few semi-colons will help.

```
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).copyTo(dest1.getRange(dest1.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12)); // here
src.getRange(r.rowStart,1,1,12).copyTo(dest2.getRange(dest2.getLastRow()+1,1,1,12)); // and here
```